# Is it possible to send the name of a table as parameter on a left join using JPA SpEL?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I am trying to do this but my IDE says is not expected (and then an error says my syntax is not correct)

I want to do this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT students.*, reports.* FROM students left join reports ON (.......) where student.id= :studentId LIMIT 1500", nativeQuery= true)
    List<Object[]> findByStudentId(@Param("studentId") long studentId);
```

My table reports might not be the same, can be for example math_report,lab_report etc... but have the same structure, so the query will be the same except for the name of the table Im joining.

Checking the doc I used

```
left join ?#{reportName} ON...
```

and of course making reportName as a parameter.

This throws an exception that cannot compile like this

Any idea how to do this? is it even possible?

Edit:

When I do the

```
left join :tableName
```

I get this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''math_report' report ON (....' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
```

I value of tableName is now math_report

Comment: When asking about code causing an error, post the code, and post the error.

Comment: My bad, please take a look